# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float TallarRatingObject.getScore()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, json, model, nullpointerexception

I want to build a model based on a json, but I encountered a null object error.

image of Json and models made in android studio

[image]

Comment: Please post your data model and json so we can help you out.

Comment: I put them into a picture

Comment: see the answer i posted. you can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your score data type in String :

```
@SerializedName("score")
private String score;

public String getScore(){
    return score;
}

public setScore(String score){
    this.score = score;
}
```